# How to set the default theme for spplot?

Tags: r, plot, gis, lattice, r-sp

Let's say, I have some spatial data and I want to plot it using `spplot` function from **sp** package:

```
library('sp')
library('lattice')
demo(meuse, ask = FALSE, echo = FALSE)
spplot(meuse.grid[,'dist'])
```

[image]

It's easy to change the theme, for example col.regions, for only one plot:

```
spplot(meuse.grid[,'dist'], col.regions=rainbow(100))
```

[image]

However, what if I want to change the col.regions for all of my plots? I've tried a few functions, for example:

```
trellis.par.set(sp.theme(set = FALSE, regions = list(col = rainbow(100)))) #1
trellis.par.set(regions = list(col = rainbow(100))) #2
lattice.options(default.theme = sp.theme(set = FALSE, regions = list(col = rainbow(100)))) #3
```

But nothing seems to work. So my question is - how to properly set the default theme for spplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the following code in order to manually re-define the default color scheme for `spplot` (see also `?spplot` where `set_col_regions` is further described).

```
## re-define default color scheme
old_theme <- get_col_regions()
new_theme <- set_col_regions(rainbow(100))

## sample data
data("meuse.grid")
coordinates(meuse.grid) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse.grid) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
gridded(meuse.grid) <- TRUE

## display data with c
spplot(meuse.grid, zcol = "dist")
```

[image: spplot]

The customized color scheme persists for any subsequently created 'spplot' object, e.g.

```
library(mapview)
spplot(poppendorf, "B007n")
```

[image: mapview]